# HTML Form intake via python

Tags: python, html

I am trying my hands on web development via python.... using default apache on rhel6.... But need some guidance

My HTML form is in /var/www/html directory:

add_employee.html:

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Fill Out This Form</h1>

<form action="../cgi-bin/process.cgi" method="POST">
First Name&emsp;: <input type="text" name="f_name"><br/>
Last  Name: <input type="text" name="l_name"><br/>
Employee ID: <input type="number" name="emp_id"><br/>
CTC : <input type="number" name="emp_ctc"><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

---

Now I am trying to fetch the form contents via python script on the backend:

process.cgi:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6


import cgi

formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
firstName = formData.getvalue('f_name')

filename="abc.txt"

txtw = open(filename,'w')
txtw.write(firstName)
```

---

But I am getting an error while passing the values via browser to file abc.txt

Below is the error being reported by the Apache HTTP error logs:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html
[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1]   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/process.cgi", line 11, in , referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html

[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1]     , referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html

[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1] txtw = open(filename,'w'), referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html

[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1] IOError, referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html

[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1] : , referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html

[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1] [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'abc.txt', referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html

[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1] , referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html

[Thu Nov 03 22:48:25 2016] [error] [client ::1] Premature end of script headers: process.cgi, referer: http:localhost/add_employee.html
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: You want to make sure you have permissions to read the file, just like the error tells you. Make sure path is right, chmod it to something readable by the user that runs apache. You're better off starting out with something like flask instead of cgi.

Comment: Checked that... The python program works fine when I simply pass a string to firstName as below:
firstName = "python"

Then the cgi is able to write to the abc.txt file. The file has full permissions otherwise too...

Comment: you have `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'abc.txt'` so Apache/python doesn't have privilages to write this file in default folder. Apache (for security) runs as different user with different privilage.

Comment: What do you mean you 'checked that'? Your cgi is clearly telling you you have a permission error. What are 'full permissions'? Fix the permission problem and you'll be fine.

Comment: below is my file permission(full) for abc.txt:

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   5 Nov  4 06:30 abc.txt

Also if I change my code to below then everything works fine:

    firstName="test"

    filename="abc.txt"

    
    txtw = open(filename,'w')

    txtw.write(firstName)


test gets written to the file successfully.

Comment: Add some basic sanity checking and error reporting because at this point you're just guessing and typing things. Check your form input or just use the higher level interface as described in the docs. Use an absolute pathname. Enable in-browser exceptions (also in the docs)